# InAppBrowser inject script (using executeScript)

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

InAppBrowser js scripts injection using `{code: 'some code'}` param is working perfectly but not with `{file: 'local file url'}` param.

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeSript({file: "myscript.js"});
});
```

how do I go about injecting script using the file param to inject my local js script?

- does it require absolute file path or relative?
- Must file be hosted on the child website?

It seem like a mysterious complicated thing to do as I have a few lines of script and can't embed it all using `ref.executeSript({codedetails, callback: "myscript.js"});`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Using cordova3.1.0.

```
ref.executeScript(
    {
        file: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"
        //webURL works fine with 'file'
    }, function()
    {　
        $.get("js/myscript.js", function(data)
        {  //workaround to obtain code using jQuery.get
            ref.executeScript(
            {
                code: data
            }, function()
            {　
                console.log('ref.executeScript done');
            });
        });
    });
```

When I set the file URL as webURL http://.... ,

it worked, but I could not figure out how to point the local js file,

so I obtain code strings using $.get "js/myscript.js".

The sample code illustrates: jQuery is already installed on the phonegap App, and also trying to use jQuery on the target inAppBrowser app. Just in case.

Comment: I include a line a follows at the beginning of my PhoneGap apps. (assuming the start page is index.html)<br /><br />


`window.basePath = window.location.href.replace('index.html', '');`
<br /><br />

Then when I need to I reference `basePath + 'js/handlebars/foo.js'` to load scripts and images the pull from the phone's filesystem.

Comment: Must have taken a long time to figure out this solution @Ken!